# JavaDoc plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javadoc

I was looking for a javadoc plugin for eclipse so that I can document for methods etc. I know in eclipse you can do <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>  but I was wondering if there was a more powerful plugin.

I use GhostDoc in VS 2008 which basically when you say document it enters all the parameters and return values and even starts the paragraph for you.

I was hoping for something like that in eclipse because with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> the only this it does is install the

```
     / ***** /* lines
```

Any help really appreciated

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) isn't available for eclipse, its c# only, I use - its great.
Does something exist similar for eclipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/ - Maybe this will satisfy you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on your method declaration with the cursor and press ALT + SHIFT + J (or right click on the method you want to document in the outline, then Source -> Generate Element Comment) Eclipse will insert all the @param and @return tags accordingly and sets the cursor to the comment.

Another nice feature is that you can press CTRL + Space in the JavaDoc comment to create links to other classes.

Comment: Under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates you can also change the templates for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is not for Eclipse but also may be useful.
I have used JavaDoc utility to generate HTML documentation for project:

```
javadoc -sourcepath "ROOT\src" com.package.name1 com.package.name2 com.package.nameN -d "javadoc_output_dir"
```